# Running Fisher’s exact test on all columns of presence/absence data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains presence/absence of a protein sequence in each sample, with each row being a different sample and each column being the protein sequence, except the last column which has the group assignment for each sample.

It looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(c(0,1,1,1,0,0), c(0,1,0,1,0,1), c(1,0,1,0,0,0), c(0, 0,0,1,1,1)
rownames(df) <- c(“AA”, “AB”, “AC”, “STATUS”)
```

I want to compute the p-value for each protein sequence (column) for Fisher’s exact test with reference to the status of the same (last column). My actual data set has over 100000 columns, so I need an efficient solution.

The challenge I am having is getting this into a contingency matrix for each protein sequence for input into fisher.test. Once this is done it could be looped for all columns except the last, but I’m not sure that this is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply` iterates over columns of a dataframe, so you can do something like:

```
l1 <- lapply(df, fisher.test, y = df$STATUS)
l1
```

> ```
> $AA
>
>   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
>
> data:  X[[i]] and .$STATUS
> p-value = 1
> alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>   0.002852567 14.836128998
> sample estimates:
> odds ratio 
>  0.3219834 
>
>
> $AB
> # output truncated...
> ```

To get just the p-values, you use `lapply` again:

```
lapply(l1, function(x) x$p.value)
```

> ```
> $AA
> [1] 1
>
> $AB
> [1] 1
>
> $AC
> [1] 0.4
>
> $STATUS
> [1] 0.1
> ```

And to get that in a usable form, you might `unlist` it:

```
unlist(lapply(l1, function(x) x$p.value))
```

> ```
>     AA     AB     AC STATUS 
>    1.0    1.0    0.4    0.1
> ```

Obviously you want to toss out the **STATUS** value, since that doesn't make much sense.

The "tidy" way of doing this is to use `purrr` and `broom`:

```
purrr::map(df, ~fisher.text(.x, df$STATUS)) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(broom::tidy, .id = "sequence")
```

> ```
>   sequence  estimate p.value    conf.low  conf.high                             method alternative
> 1       AA 0.3219834     1.0 0.002852567  14.836129 Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data   two.sided
> 2       AB 3.1057504     1.0 0.067403027 350.561487 Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data   two.sided
> 3       AC 0.0000000     0.4 0.000000000   4.922984 Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data   two.sided
> 4   STATUS       Inf     0.1 0.647974586        Inf Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data   two.sided
> ```

But I don't know which method would be faster for that many columns.

Also you should probably be concerned with your error rate with that many tests. Are you planning to adjust the p-values by some method (e.g. Bonferroni)?

Comment: I wanted to use this as a feature selection method to identify variables that would be most useful in classification based on p-value. I’m not too familiar with the stats, so would you recommend a p-value correction for this? If you could explain the reasoning for a high(?) error rate with this method I would appreciate it.

Comment: @JackArnestad, that's a question for https://stats.stackexchange.com, where people may be more versed in your domain.

Comment: You're probably fine using the tests as a filter rather than hypothesis testing, but make sure you're using it appropriately for your goal. You can find a good discussion about this exact topic on [research gate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Fisher_and_correction_for_multiple_testing2), and like @Brian suggested, see about input from [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: R has a `p.adjust` function.